# Programmatic way to find application that is blocking port creation

Tags: c, sockets, udp

To run some simulator we installed Windows Services for Unix.
This uses an UDP port 1035,

In some PC's this Windows service for Unix works fine, but in others it fails.
After some analysis I found that this is due to some Security application.

Now, this application will be installed in 100s of PCs and most of them with various security application.

I would like to write a tool that would find the application that blocks the UDP port creation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a tool. netstat will tell you.

Comment: @EJP, Can you tell me how, NetStat will come to know which application is trying to block the port creation? In case there is a way, can you elaborate, I will also search the internet ~

Comment: Search the internet? Ask on a forum? Don't be silly. netstat -? will tell you all its options.

Comment: netstat -b displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port.

Comment: @Alphaneo, did you read through and understand the answer? You don't need to ask on forums or search the Internet when your own computer already contains the answer.

Comment: @EJP Cool, Will netstat, it also point to some "Security application" like Antivirus software, that would monitor and prevent port access?